# In angular and openlayers, set the name of the map points to be dynamic

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-5

I am using angular6 and openlayers5.

The scenario is that the user does a search and some features are get from the database and rendered on a OL vector layer. The features already have a name at this point, that came from the database (postgresql), so that is the name they have when they are rendered on the map.

Then the user can click on any of those to edit. There is a textfield that contains the name of the feature, but can be edited.

I would like to edit the name of the feature on the map, while the name of the textfield is being edited. Right now I am editing the name in the textfield, but the name on the map does not change and this will surely confuse users.

What I have now. I am getting a GeoJSON after each search and put it on the layer.

```
  const results = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data.data);      
  this.myvectorsource.addFeatures(results);
```

When a feature is clicked, I get its name and put it in an object.

```
this.currentPoint.name = this.selectClick.getFeatures().item(0).values_.name;
```

then I have a function that gets all the extra details of that feature from the database and puts them in an angular reactive form by resetting it with the values

```
nameField:[data.name]
```

Finally, this is the feature styling function that takes care of the feature's text on the map (inspired by the original OL example)

```
const getText = (feature,resolution) => {
  let text="";
  if(feature.values_.name){
    text = feature.values_.name;
  }
  else{
    text = this.currentPoint.name;
  }      
  return text;
};
```

I tried doing something like

```
text = this.editingForm.get('editingFormNameGroup').get('nameField').value
```

But this does not update the name on the map as the textfield editing is happening.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: just update the property of feature will not cause an update of the layer automatically, you should refresh the source/layer manually after edit.

Comment: @zhimin Thaks. I will test this.